# Suspending a PowerShell script until a action is complete i.e. opening & closing Notepad

Tags: powershell, scripting

Is there a way of suspending a PowerShell script until some action has been completed. For example if I was using a Linux shell and I typed `gedit` then gedit would load but the shell would be suspended until I closed gedit (unless '&' was added to the end of the command).

Is there anyway to mimick this behaviour with PowerShell? So could I get a script to open Notepad but suspend itself until Notepad was closed again.

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pipe to Out-Null and PowerShell will wait until the windows app closes:

```
PS> notepad | out-null
```

Or as the previous poster points out:

```
PS> (Start-Process notepad -PassThru).WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, I've found that the out-null works the best. It's just what I was looking for.

Comment: this is wonderful, and if you create an alias it's better, something like: & 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' @args | out-null

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class and call the `.WaitForExit` method after setting the appropriate `ProcessInfo` properties to launch Notepad.

Comment: This is the only way we could figure it out as well, oddly though it does not work for msi's. I think because of the msi service, and multiple msi processes involved it just returns no matter what. Be interesting to see if someone else has a different way.

Comment: Thanks guillermooo combined with the second part of Keiths response that works as well, just a little more long winded.